# Controller code to create a record that has two belongs_to relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many, belongs-to

I can create a `statistic` for a given `person` like this:

```
@person = Person.find(person.id)
@statistic = @person.statistics.build(:value => @value, :updated => @updated)
```

There's a `one-to-many` (`has_many`/`belongs_to`) relationship between `person` and `statistic`.

The above works fine.

However, I also want the `statistic` to belong to a `race` too (race as in running/driving race) i.e. I have changed my `statistic` model to have two `belongs_to`s:

```
belongs_to :person # just had this before
belongs_to :race   # this is new
```

Is the above correct or do I need to use a `through` in my models somehow?  If so, how?

How do I alter my controller code for this change?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `statistic` to belong to `race` only, you don't need to use `has_many :through`. All you need to do is to add the new reference when building a `statistic` entry by either a new object:

```
@race = Race.new(....)
@person.statistics.build(value: @value, updated: @updated, race: @race)
```

or by foreign key (if the referenced race already exists)

```
@person.statistics.build(value: @value, updated: @updated, race_id: @race.id)
```